# Locus of points with reducible fibers over moment map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a Fano manifold of Picard rank one such that the cotangent bundle $T^*X$ is completely algebraically integrable system. Let $\mu: T^*X \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be the moment map, where $n$ is the dimension of $X$.  It is known that a general fiber of $\mu$ is irreducible.

Question: Is it possible to impose some condition on $X$ such that $W=: \{v \in \mathbb{C}^n: \mu^{-1}(v) \text{ is reducible }\}$ has codimension $\ge 2$ ?

Comment: by reducible do you mean disconnected fibres also? or just reducible and connected? also it might be helpful if you also put some condition on the singularities of the fibres.

Comment: By reducible, I meant disconnected fiber also.  What would be the answer for connected reducible case ?

Comment: We do not have any control on the singularities on the fibers.